# Missing Cloud Messaging section in Firebase Console

Tags: firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-console

just like in title above. I am unable add cloud messaging section to the project settings.

[image: project_settings]

This is odd because it's invisible only for one project, other projects even those which don't have enabled cloud messaging have this section visible. This section is needed to add server key or configure project for mobile. The question is, how to add Cloud Messaging section to project settings.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you a project owner? I think this might be about user permission.

Comment: It turns out that I have permissions to the rest of the projects but not this one. Yes this was a permission issue.

Comment: @Matt199 Can this work with custom permission rather than giving `Owner` access to the user? I have been provided with the [following roles](https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/iam/permissions#messaging) but cannot see the cloud messaging section still

Comment: @user121095 unfortunately you need Firebase Admin access to get access to cloud messaging section